# Where can I find system call number for RISC-V

Tags: riscv

I'm trying to do some low level stuff, so I need to know the system call number of `open` on riscv32 platform.

The only thing close to my problem is in [here](https://fedora.juszkiewicz.com.pl/syscalls.html), but it doesn't show the number of `open`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `openat (AT_FDCWD, ...)` instead.  Passing the `AT_FDCWD` argument for the first argument `dirfd` makes it perform exactly the same as `open`.  The rest of the arguments are the same as `open`.